# Is it posible to have the w3 validator ignore php tags

Tags: php, html, w3c-validation

It ( [online validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) ) is pulling errors for my php tags.

I have to manually remove all the php inserts to get my html to validate.

Is there a better way to do this?

Here is the first error:

```
Line 24, Column 6: Saw <?. Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing instruction in HTML. (XML processing instructions are not supported in HTML.)

    <?php
```

Comment: The validator validates HTML. raw php code is NOT valid html, and never will be. the validator should be fed what your php script produces as output.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't put your php file through the validator. You should put the resulting output through the validator

Answer (score 0):

A quote from the [W3 Online Validtor](http://validator.w3.org/) website.

> "This validator checks the markup validity of Web documents in HTML,
>   XHTML, SMIL, MathML, etc."

It doesn't validate PHP. But the output will be validated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running local server and try to check if your HTML is valid, then just open your page in browser, copy **rendered** page source to clipboard (via view->source in your browser's top menu, or similar), and paste it [>>here<<](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)